# Change background to only one inputbox at a time jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to change a div's background when i click an input box, i tried this but it changes all the backgrounds to all the div's containing the input boxes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".djform_row :input").on('click', function () {
        $(".djform_field").css("background", "red");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".djform_row :input").on('blur', function () {
        $(".djform_field").css("background", "yellow");
    });
});
```

Comment: now you have to post relevant HTML code. That's ok, i just called a medium and he told me: `$(this).closest('div').find(".djform_field").css("background", "red");`  PS: adeneo knows a better guy than me, i guess...

Comment: The code is too big to be posted here, I`m using joomla and I have a "add item" page wich contains ALOT of inputboxes, select boxes, text areas... .djform_row is the container of .djform_field witch contains inputboxes.

Comment: the relevant code is too big? I don't think so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the DIV has the class `djform_field` and is a parent of the input, something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".djform_row :input").on({
        focus: function () {
             $(this).closest(".djform_field").css("background", "red");
        },
        blur: function () {
             $(this).closest(".djform_field").css("background", "yellow");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @A.Wolff - I don't really like guessing wildly, but this one seemed somewhat obvious, and closest used with an input that can't have children anyway should capture almost anything, or at least the most common layouts for the markup.